# Unable to install Windows 10 couldn't create partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, windows-10, partitioning

I am trying to clean install Windows 10 in my Asus X555L Notebook Laptop, but every time I land on the "*Where do you want to install Windows ?* " page and create "*New* " partitions with the unallocated space, I always get this error:

`We couldn't create a new partition. [Error: 0xd40e0530]`

I tried using Diskpart in <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, then "*create new partition"* after "*clean*"-ing, but then UEFI mode requires a GPT partition. Sometimes I get through the partition creation, but will get this error (even in Diskpart):

"`We couldn't format this partition`"

I believe there's nothing wrong with my Windows 10 installation media (via USB 2.0 stick), coz I used it on my other laptop and it worked fine.

Please help me. Is my HDD dead?

This image below shows the first error I encountered (before "Delete"-ing it)

[image: Click to see]

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete the partition to remove the mbr partition table.

Once you delete the partition, you will have 465.8 GB unallocated space.

Now you can either create new partitions or install windows on entire disk.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read what the error is telling you. It is trying to use EFI and your disk has MBR. Delete the disk completely (you currently have 0.0 MB of free space) and setup from there.